# Table View reuse cell behaviour in case of different Section scenario

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am quite confused when to know the behaviour of table **reusability** and **memory allocation** concept under certain scenarios. I am mentioning some below as well as a detailed description of my understanding -

**1) When cells of the table view are of same design and with one section all together :**

***My understanding -*** Here the table view visible cells are allocated memory once and the same memory for those cells are reused when we scroll up/down in the table view.

**2) When there is more than one cell designs with different reuse id's and one section.**

Here similar cells are reused & different cells i.e with different reuse iD's are allocated new memory.

**3) Where there is one cell design/cell reuse Id but more than one section-**

Here also the visible cells will be reused since we have the same cell with same reuseID no matter what are the number of sections we have.

**4) Where there is >1 cell design/cell reuseId but more than one section-**

Here also it depends when and where are we using different cell's with different reuseID's at that point allocation of new memory location is being done.

**5) Does reusing of cells have anything to do with different sections ?**

So kindly check my understanding on this fact and amend me if I am wrong at any point?

Comment: Your all point of view is right